# Preseed installation doesn't autoconfirm VG creation?

Tags: partitioning, lvm, preseed

I setup a preseed configuration file for disk partitioning on Ubuntu:

```
d-i partman-auto/disk /dev/sda1
d-i partman-auto/disk /dev/sda2 
d-i partman-auto/disk /dev/sda3
d-i partman-auto/method string lvm
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string rootvg
d-i partman-auto-lvm/new_vg_name string infravg
d-i partman-auto/choose_recipe select diod
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe diod :: \
            255 256 256 ext4                        \
            $primary{ }                             \
            $bootable{ }                            \
            method{ format }                        \
            format{ }                               \
            use_filesystem{ }                       \
            filesystem{ ext4 }                      \
            label{ boot }                           \
            mountpoint{ /boot } .                   \
            12000 12288 12288 ext4                  \
            $primary{ }                             \
            method{ lvm }                           \
            format{ }                               \
            device{ /dev/sda2 }                     \
            vg_name{ rootvg } .                     \
            28000 28672 28672 ext4                  \
            $primary{ }                             \
            method{ lvm }                           \
            format{ }                               \
            device{ /dev/sda3 }                     \
            vg_name{ infravg } .                    \
            100 1 100000 ext4                       \
            method{ format }                        \
            format{ }                               \
            use_filesystem{ }                       \
            filesystem{ ext4 } .                    \
            2500 1 2560 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ var_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /var } .                    \
            2000 1 2048 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ usr_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /usr } .                    \
            1000 1 1024 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ root_lv }                      \
            method{ format }                        \
            format{ }                               \
            use_filesystem{ }                       \
            filesystem{ ext4 }                      \
            mountpoint{ / } .                       \
            1000 1 1024 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ home_lv }                      \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /home } .                   \
            1000 1 1024 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ tmp_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /tmp } .                    \
            1000 1 1024 linux-swap                  \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ swap }                         \
            method{ swap } format{ } .              \
            512 1 512 ext4                          \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ opt_lv }                       \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /opt } .                    \
            128 1 128 ext4                          \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ system_lv }                    \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /system } .                 \
            100 1 100000 ext4                       \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ rootvg }               \
            lv_name{ free1_lv }                     \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 } .  \
            1000 1 1024 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ infravg }              \
            lv_name{ chef_lv }                      \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /opt/chef } .               \
            4000 1 4096 ext4                        \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ infravg }              \
            lv_name{ images_lv }                    \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ /images } .                 \
            100 1 100000 ext4                       \
            $lvmok{ } in_vg{ infravg }              \
            lv_name{ free2_lv }                     \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            .

d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

Everything works fine, the 3 primary partitions are done correctly, each LV is created correctly and with the right size, but there is one issue I can't seem to find the fix for it (I've tried various changes to the file, still no luck).

Everytime the automatic installation runs I ALWAYS have to confirm the two VG's creation (rootvg & infravg). After I confirm this, the installer will continue automatically (confirm and write changes to disk).

Do you have any guidance or tips on how to automatically confirm VG creation via the recipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that adding `d-i partman-auto-lvm/guided_size string max` fixed the issue.

This basically tells partman/preseed to use 100% of the disk space allocated for the volume groups/logical volumes in the config file.